# iPhone, how'd I override a tab bar button to do other than the navigation controller in my mainWindow.xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

At the moment I have all my views specified in my mainWindow.xib file in interface builder.

So when a tab bar button is tapped it loads the correct navigation controller.

But I want to do something different in code when they tap the tab bar button for one button.

How do I do that?

EDIT - Not quite working solution...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a delegate to your tabBar and have it implement the method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbc didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)newSelection
```

this way, you will be able to do whatever you want to new selected view Controller and the tabBar itself.

Comment: Ok, I've added the delegate but I'm getting an error ` error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'UITabBarControllerDelegete'`. Also what do I put in didSelectViewController ? I'll have to determine which button was pressed ?

Comment: UITabBarControllerDelegete  should be UITabBarControllerDelegate, no?

Comment: You will know which tab was pressed using tbc.selectedIndex;

Comment: If your return NO to shouldSelectViewController, you won't be notified on didSelectViewController. You should probably do your graph stuf in the shouldSelectViewController just before returning NO

Comment: AFAIK selectedIndex is updated after shouldSelectViewController, so you cant use that to determine whether to return true or false. You need to use the viewController parameter.

Comment: may be you should try to test the className? 
"if([viewController isKindOfClass:[TheClassName class]])"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UITabBarControllerDelegate methods to call custom code. Use shouldSelectViewController and put your custom code in there.

Also, I recommend to not put all the views in the same .xib file. Separating them inproves performance because it doesn't have to load all the objects at once.

Comment: I`m not sure how to use shouldSelectViewController? , see my screen shot about. It is doing something, but I`m not sure what